# How to serve multiple directories in one path using connect

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

In my file system i have two directories containing subdirectories:

- directory1

  - directory1_1
- directory2

  - directory2_1

I want to serve both root directories (directory1, directory2) under the path /resources.
I tried to achieve this using serve-index (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index):

```
app.use("/resources", serveIndex("/directory1", {icons:true}));
app.use("/resources", serveIndex("/directory2", {icons:true}));
```

The problem is, only the structure of directory1 is shown - directory2 is ignored.
I am looking for a way to serve the merged content of multiple directories.
Any ideas?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Any reason not to use the build in static module? http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

Comment: You will need to create an endpoint for `/ressource` that will merge and serve the two directories. `serveIndex` can only serve one directory at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As i did not find a module, i implemented my own local module and took serve-index as a starting point.
The API now looks like this:

```
app.use("/resources", serveMergedIndex([ "directory1", "directory2" ]));
```

2 hours of work but works pretty well.

Thanks, Thomas